# How to Parse Google Speech API response in text box

Tags: c#, parsing, httpresponse, jsonresult, google-speech-api

I am working on google speech API in c#.

Google is returning results with no problem and its response is shown on my text box.

Now I want  limited text to be displayed on text box. As given response below, I want only recognized text to be displayed e.g. the Text box should display `you said Ball`.

Result string and alternative transcripts should be eliminated.

this is the response from google speech API when I said Ball:

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[
   {"alternative":[
       {"transcript":"boa"},
       {"transcript":"ball"},
       {"transcript":"bull"},
       {"transcript":"boys"},
       {"transcript":"call"}
       ],
       "final":true}
    ],
"result_index":0}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the job of you, but next time, please use the code formatting button to format code, and if possible (like in this JSON response), make the code readable by using indentions etc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your guidance. I am new to Stack Overflow but next time i will be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass the `single_utterance` option to `StreamingRecognitionConfig`.  There's some more information available here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.StreamingRecognitionConfig

If you're not going to use the alternatives, you can also set `maxAlternatives` to 1 or leave it with the default of 1.  `interim_results` should also be set to the default value of `false`.

I'm not sure the exact syntax in C#.  You'll still have to pick out the final transcript, but there will be less unwanted information in the response.